# How can I invert the negated condition and swap the if-else branch in this ruby syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax

VS Code is showing a squiggly line on this line and I wonder why.
Here is the line of code:

```
if answer != ""
```

It says:

> Invert the negated condition and swap the if-else branches.

Find below the code snippet

```
def coach_answer(your_message)
  if your_message.downcase == "i am going to work right now!"
    ""
  elsif your_message.end_with?("?")
    "Silly question, get dressed and go to work!"
  else
    "I don't care, get dressed and go to work!"
  end
end

def coach_answer_enhanced(your_message)
  answer = coach_answer(your_message)
  if answer != ""
    if your_message.upcase == your_message
      "I can feel your motivation! #{answer}"
    else
      answer
    end
  else
    ""
  end
end
```

Comment: "VS Code is showing a squiggly line on this line and I wonder why." Well, do you see an error message? Did you try hovering over that text, to see if an error pops up?

Comment: Yes, I tried and here is the message "Invert the negated condition and swap the if-else branches."

Comment: Try replace `if answer != ""` to `unless answer == ""`

Comment: That isn't an error message. It's a *suggestion* from the IDE about how to improve the clarity of the code. When it makes these kinds of suggestions, you should see a link or button to apply the change automatically. You can see what happens and then undo it if you don't like it. This is not a question about Ruby or about writing code; it is a question about your IDE and how to use it.

Comment: Anyway, it isn't clear to me what the question is. Do you *understand* the suggestion? Do you know what each word means? For example, do you know what "invert" means? Do you know what a "condition" is? Do you know what it's referring to as the "negated condition"? Do you understand what the "branches" are of the if-else?

Comment: Instead of `answer != ""` you could also write `!answer.empty?` Or `answer.present?` when you are using Rails.

Answer (score 2):

When VS says *"Invert the negated condition and swap the if-else branches"* it means that you should convert your code from:

```
if obj != expression
  # branch A
else
  # branch B
end
```

to:

```
if obj == expression
  # branch B
else
  # branch A
end
```

The negated condition `!=` was inverted to become `==` and accordingly, the `if` branch *"branch A"* and the `else` branch *"branch B"* were swapped.

---

Applied to your code, it suggests to write it this way:

```
def coach_answer_enhanced(your_message)
  answer = coach_answer(your_message)
  if answer == ""
    ""
  else
    if your_message.upcase == your_message
      "I can feel your motivation! #{answer}"
    else
      answer
    end
  end
end
```